# Render Math equation in flutter from image

Tags: flutter, dart, rendering, ocr, mobile-application

I need to convert the mathematical equation that I have as an image to data.I'm not sure if converting something to HTML, JSON, or SVG is the best course of action. Could someone please explain how to use Flutter to render the math equation graphic in a mobile app?,
I will attach the image for your reference  [image: math equation]